# Powershell: Getting error - New-ADOrganizationalUnit : Cannot convert 'System.Object[]' to the type

Tags: powershell

I need to create an Organization Unit via command. I am executing the following command:

```
New-ADOrganizationalUnit "test_unit_80" –Path "DC=abc,DC=test,DC=com" -ProtectedFromAccidentalDeletion:$false
```

It is working fine when I am running it directly on the powershell or command prompt. But when I an trying the execute the same via a powershell script it is throwing the following error:

```
New-ADOrganizationalUnit : Cannot convert 'System.Object[]' to the type
'System.String' required by parameter 'Path'. Specified method is not
supported.
At line:1 char:191


+ ... it_80â?? -Path â?oDC=abc,DC=test,DC=comâ??
-ProtectedFromAccidentalDeletion ...
+                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [New-ADOrganizationalUnit],
    ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotConvertArgument,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.
   Management.Commands.NewADOrganizationalUnit
```

This is how I writing the code in the powershell script:

```
New-ADOrganizationalUnit “test_unit_80” -Path “DC=DC=abc,DC=test,DC=com” -ProtectedFromAccidentalDeletion:\`$false;
```

Can anyone point out what is going wrong in the above line of code? *emphasized text*

Comment: Replace those smart quotes (`“...”`) with simple double-quotes (`"..."`) and it'll work. What editor did you use to write the script?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen, I am using notepad++ to write the script. And following your suggestion it did resolve this error. But it gave rise to a new error as follows: 


New-ADOrganizationalUnit : Cannot convert 'System.String' to the type
'System.Nullable`1[System.Boolean]' required by parameter
'ProtectedFromAccidentalDeletion'.


Can you please say why is it not able to read the value 'false' for the ProtectedFromAccidentalDeletion parameter?

Comment: Remove the attempted escape sequence, it should just be `-ProtectedFromAccidentalDeletion:$false`

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen, I tried that but still the same error is coming...

Comment: Are you _sure_? Does it still say ``Cannot convert 'System.String' to the type 'System.Nullable`1[System.Boolean]'`` exactly?

Comment: Hi @MathiasR.Jessen, yes it gives the following error now: 
New-ADOrganizationalUnit : Cannot convert 'System.String' to the type
'System.Nullable`1[System.Boolean]' required by parameter
'ProtectedFromAccidentalDeletion'.


At line:1 char:249
+ ... dentalDeletion:false;
+                    ~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [New-ADOrganizationalUnit],
    ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotConvertArgument,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.
   Management.Commands.NewADOrganizationalUnit

Comment: You didn't include the `$`. It should be `-ProtectedFromAccidentalDeletion:$false`

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen I tried having both with $ and without $. In both cases it is giving the same error.

Comment: The hyphen in front of parameter `Path` in the first code line you show is called an [Em-Dash](https://www.html.am/html-codes/character-codes/html-em-dash-code.cfm). You need to retype that. Next, as Mathias already explained, you should not use curly smart-quotes in code, so retype those too.. I'm afraid you are relying on copy pasting from the internet with this, but by doing so you end up with markup characters that do not belong in code...